# How to change the location of the menu

Tags: menus

The theme I am using places the menu next to the logo (see the attached image). But I prefer to have the menu under the logo. How can I do it?
[image: menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the GeneratePress theme for you; adding this custom CSS should do it:

```
.nav-float-right .inside-header .main-navigation {
    float: none !important;
}
```

EDIT: Or, as **Madalin** showed, a non-!important version:

```
html .nav-float-right .inside-header .main-navigation {
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using '!important' for usability reasons. Instead, do it like so:

```
html .nav-float-right .inside-header .main-navigation {
    float: none;
}
```

You want to add it in the style.css file of the child theme.

Thanks!